# Pyodbc loses connection after 2 hours to MS SQL Server when run in Python Anaconda environment

Tags: sql-server, anaconda, windows-10, pyodbc, python-3.8

I recently upgraded the `python` version I was running in a `Windows 10` environment from `3.5`->`3.8`, with both being run in in the `Anaconda` environment, and specifically with the `QTConsole`. After the upgrade, the `QTConsole` connection to the `MS SQL Server` is becoming unstable every 1-2 hours. Previously on `3.5` I was using `pyodbc 3.0.10` and that was able (and is still able) to maintain a stable connection to the `MS SQL Server`. With `3.8`, I am using `pyodbc 4.0.30` (I was originally using `4.0.0` but I upgraded and that extended the timeout time from 1 hour -> 2 hours). I suspect it might be a permissions issue.

I should note that I launch the `3.8 QTConsole` from the `Anaconda Navigator`, which can only start up with `admin` credentials. The Windows `profile` running the `app` cannot run the `Navigator` or even open a basic `Command Prompt`. I did not require the `Navigator` or elevated credentials to run the `3.5 QT Console`, and can still run `3.5` and connect to the `MS SQL Server` without any difficulties.

When I try and run the `app` in the same `QTConsole` window after about 2 hours the `app` will intermittently get this error when trying to connect to the `SQL Server`:

```
'28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. 
(18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed. 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452)
```

I can re-establish the connection by shutting down the current `QTConsole` and opening a new one, which will again allow the `app` to connect for ≈ 2 hours before getting the above `error` again. Eventually, after around 6 hours, the `Navigator` appears to lose its `admin` credentials as well, and I can no longer open up `QTConsoles` requiring that I close out of the `Navigator` and re-open with `admin` credentials.

Here is the connection string I use to connect in both `3.5` and `3.8`:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(server='server', database='SQL DB',
           Trusted_Connection='yes', driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}')
```

Which is where I get the `error`.

Not sure if permissions are coming into play exactly, but maybe because the `app profile` cannot execute a `command prompt` that is preventing `Anaconda` from running some command to keep the database connection active after the `admin` credentials timeout?

Comment: Connections are meant to be opened right before they're used and closed immediately afterward. They aren't meant to be left open for 2 hours. That's because any locks taken during a connection remain until either the current transaction ends or the connection closes. Apart from that, the latest version of the SQL Server ODBC driver is 17.

Comment: You need to upgrade the ODBC driver and fix the code so it doesn't keep  the connection open for so long. You didn't post any code though, so it's hard to say what should change

Comment: The connections are closed after each query execution, none of which are longer than a minute or two. It is the `QTConsole` that has its ability to connect expire. Even if I hard reset the console with `ctrl + .` I still am unable to re-connect to the database. I will try upgrading the driver and see if that improves stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on troubleshooting I did, I am pretty sure the problem is that to run `Python 3.8` with `Anaconda` you need `Windows Command Prompt` Read & Read + Execute privileges. To run on `Anaconda Python 3.5` in the `QTConsole` you do not need these privileges (though you do need `Admin` privileges to install obviously).

This is not an `Anaconda` issue, in fact without `Anaconda` I could not even run in `3.5` since the only other way to run a Python app in Windows without the `Anaconda` environment that I know of is to just run through a Windows `command prompt`, which I do not have access to do.